# "Cannot open log file" - Kile is not able to identify log file location

Tags: errors, kile

I am using kile for my latex documentation.

I wanted to keep the top level directory of tex files clean, 
so I have created a folder named "tmp" in the current directory 
and added the option to compilation as:

> `pdflatex --output-directory tmp`

using kile's build-configuration settings.

After setting this, compilation is working very fine and the directory is clean as I desired, but the "log and messages" pane in Kile, at the bottom is not able to show the compilation status message and says:

> `Cannot open log file; did you run LaTeX?`

Any suggestions about how do I tell KILE about new log file location??

---

**Solution update 7-Nov-2016:**

Below is a compromising work-around for this age-old, unsolved bug/problem with kile. (As the Q is closed and I only can edit the Q):

Basically the aim is to keep the current directory clean, so one may compromise to ONE additional file, more specifically a link to the .log file.
Note that we already avoided a ton of other files.

So the main problem happens to be a simple bug, that the .log file is not accessible to the kile, hence complaining as above. Because kile is (in spite of the relative directory setting) still thinking that the log file should exist in the current directory to read and present its summary in "log and messages".

So I kept a symbolic link to the actual log file (which should have been created in `tmp` directory as a result of the option `--output-directory`) in the current directory, i.e.:

> `ln -s tmp/<filename>.log <filename>.log`

This has solved the error message and everything else is normal.

Comment: please test if the following works for you: settings -> tools -> build -> PDFLaTeX -> advanced -> add `./tmp` into `relative dir`. Save, restart Kile and test.

Comment: @dcmst Thanks for the reply. 
This idea doesn't seem to work! (checked it twice)

Comment: Ok, so you have two possibilities: 1) update Kile to version 3 beta1 (you need to compile the source code yourself). In that version the `relative dir` setting will work (tested here). 2) If you can't/don't want to update, a workaround would be to simlink only the log file in the top level directory, so that Kile will see it.

Comment: Thanks @dcmst, thats a nice suggestion. 

So, I've been using version 2.1.3 which came automatically. Lets see if somebody can give an authentic solution dealing with kile internals...

Comment: the authentic solution is the update to latest trunk/beta version, your version has a bug which prevents the `relative dir` setting to work. The `relative dir` is there to do exactly what you want to do. Or you can wait until Kile 3 comes out, but it may take a while...

Comment: Thats fine. I am going to do the same as you said. Just curious to know one thing. Is true that nothing can be done at this version itself, when it has a bug?

Comment: I'm glad to know this is a bug and not just me. Is it also a bug that if I set relative directory, I can't then get rid of it without recreating the build tools and deleting the contaminated ones? (Also, it deletes many of my custom keyboard shortcuts in this case.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a bug in Kile